# Laravel get file content

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('marquee', function(){
    echo  File::get('\storage\app\marquee.json');
});
```

I have a json file place inside storage/app

My question is how can I read this content from controller or route?

Comment: Did you tried `File::get('marquee.json')` ?

Comment: not working too, cant get correct file path

Comment: Try this  `File::get(asset('storage/app/marquee.json'));`

Comment: Where's the file? `/storage/app/` implies that it's the the filesystem root.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `Storage` facade:

```
Storage::disk('local')->get('marquee.json');
```

The old way, using `File` facade (deprecated for Laravel 7):

```
File::get(storage_path('app/marquee.json'));
```

Comment: For those wanting to access files at the project root (above the storage directory), use: File::get(base_path() . 'marquee.json')

Comment: I am using Laravel 7, File::get() requires an import, what do I import? I want to import data.json from the database/data directory in the project @JarrettBarnett

Comment: Seems File might be deprecated for Laravel 7. Use Storage::get() instead. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: @ChrisClaude the FIle facade has namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
File::get(storage_path('app\marquee.json'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can go with the absolute path

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::get(base_path() . '/storage/app/marquee.json');
```

Comment: In our Vapor deployed app, we needed to access a json file inside our seeders and no solutions worked, except we putting `base_path()` in-front of the file path as above. FYI.

Answer (score 5):

You can use *storage_path()*  function for locate the storage folder and then join app folder name like that:

```
$path = storage_path() . "/app/marquee.json";
echo  File::get($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store files in your storage folder in Laravel:

```
$path = storage_path() . "/json/${filename}.json";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

From external source use Http requests, documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client), eg:

```
$response = Http::get('http://test.com');
```